# setFormula by using script in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a little knowledge of javascript I just want to know how to make a script that works in these scenario[image: setFormula]

I just want to set the second-row with D2:F2, or as long as the first row has a value to be a reference in the formula like in cells: D2={franco!F2:F}; E2={justin!F2:F}; F2 ={aeron!F2:F} and so on... 
currently I am using the following codes:

```
function setFormula() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rangeList = ss.getRange('d1:f1').getValue();
  var range = ss.getRange('d2:f2');
  range.setValue('={'+rangeList+'!F2:F}');
}
```

hope that someone can help me with this code. Thank you in advance

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about your current issue and your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: hi Tanaike, so if I run the setFormula function it will automatically set formula for. the following cells D2={franco!F2:F}; E2={justin!F2:F}; F2 ={aeron!F2:F} by using the script.Thank you

Comment: Thank you for replying. You want to put the formulas of `{franco!F2:F}`, `{justin!F2:F}` and `{aeron!F2:F}` to the cells "D2", "E2" and "F2" using Google Apps Script, respectively. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes thats correct thank you

Comment: I appreciate your time Tanaike, thank you

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to put the formulas of `{franco!F2:F}`, `{justin!F2:F}` and `{aeron!F2:F}` to the cells "D2", "E2" and "F2", respectively.
- In this case, you want to retrieve the values of `franco, justin, aeron` from the cells "D1:F1".
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

I could understand like above. For this, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Sample script:

```
function setFormula() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rangeList = ss.getRange('d1:f1').getValues()[0];
  var range = ss.getRange('d2:f2');
  range.setFormulas([rangeList.map(function(e) {return '={'+e+'!F2:F}'})]);
}
```

- At first, the values of `franco, justin, aeron` are retrieved. Using these values, each formula is creted in the loop with `map`
- `setFormulas` uses the 2 dimensional array. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setFormulas()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulasformulas)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: I think its Ok, but is there a way that it will automatically will make a formula not using this  var formulas = [["={franco!F2:F}", "={justin!F2:F}", "={aeron!F2:F}"]]; but using only this range.setValue('={'+rangeList+'!F2:F}'); that will do the formula for each D2,E2 AND F2 instead of only one cell it will be for the rest cells respectively. rangeList  based from D1,E1,F1, VALUES are franco justin and aeron respectively

Comment: @Franc Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I think that now I could correctly understand about your goal. Could you please wait a minute?

Comment: @Franc Thank you for replying. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Yes this is what I need. thank you for the help. You're the best

Comment: @Franc Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too. And I added tags for your question.

Comment: Yes, @Tanaike Thank you for your time. God bless